# ubuntu 13.10 update problem. No menu, can't launch terminal, no results in dash

Tags: updates, 13.10

Performed update today.  It wanted to restart, so I let it.  Looked at it later on and it is missing the menu bar.  Could move the mouse around, but the launcher is permanently visible (I have it set to autohide).  Ctrl-alt-del does not bring up shutdown/restart buttons. Ctrl-alt-t does not bring up terminal.  Have to shut down using power button.  Able to boot in recovery mode, but menu bar is still missing.  Can get into terminal using root shell from grub boot menu.  Not sure what to do here.  Is there a way to roll back today's updates?

Comment: I should add that I can click on icons in the launcher, and they pulse as though they are going to open, but then nothing happens.  Can bring up dash with super key, but nothing is ever found.  Meanwhile, my desktop is still littered with the usual icons, so I suspect nothing has actually been deleted.

Comment: After reinstalling today and wasting a ton of time surfing for answers, I am suspecting I could have solved this by booting into the old kernel, but I'm not sure and can't try.  Unfortunately now I am dealing with the blank screen, blinking cursor on my fresh install (tried both 12.10 and 13.04) and I can't get grub menu to start (shift not working).  This used to be so much easier...

Comment: Took several attempts to reinstall.  Followed same procedure each time, alternating between my 12.10 and 13.04 USB installers.  Did not change them.  After about 5 installs, it finally booted normally.  Upgraded to 13.10 against my better judgement, but seems to be working OK.  No idea what happened with the update fail the other day.

Comment: Current issues I am having with 13.10: my persistent xrandr script forcing 1368x768 resolution on 1280x600 screen does not function correctly anymore.  I had placed a line in lightdm.conf which worked nicely in 12.10/13.04.  Also, I am having the touchpad issue I have seen mentioned elsewhere.  Messed with system settings and dconf-editor to no effect.  What works is running the following instead: synclient VertEdgeScroll=1